# How to display the JSON Object data in Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, json, apexrest

I am trying to Display the JSON Object in VF page but I get the result like this, How do i get the list individually and iterate it in Pageblocktable.

[This is the reference link building something like this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208572/google-books-and-salesforce-integration-by-rest-api?rq=1)

But I see the Output like this once i hit Search,
[image: This is the Output]

And Simple VF

```
    <apex:page controller="SearchBooks" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!callsearch}" value="Search" id="theButton"/>
</apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!result}" var="item">
        <apex:column value="{!item}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

This is my Class

```
public class SearchBooks {
public GoogleBooksResponse result { get; set; }     

 public class Items {
    public String kind {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public String etag {get;set;} 
    public String selfLink {get;set;} 

}

public searchBooksApi callsearch() {
    String s;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter');
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = null;
    res = http.send(req);
    s = res.getBody();
    GoogleBooksResponse result = (GoogleBooksResponse)  System.JSON.deserialize(s , GoogleBooksResponse.class);
    this.result = result;
    return null;
}
```

}

This the GoogleBooksResponse

```
public class GoogleBooksResponse{
public  String kind;
public  Integer totalItems;
public  List<items> items; //Your existing class.

public class Items {
    public String kind {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public String etag {get;set;} 
    public String selfLink {get;set;} 

}

}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer for your question is there in the link in your question. de-serialize using a wrapper class and display it in UI

Comment: [Edit] the controller into this post. It may have changed between questions, and you may add or change it in response to comments.

Comment: I have edited my post, But how to iterate each single items? @RedDevil

Comment: If I want to display Etag and SelfLink how do i do that?

Comment: Please paste the structure of GoogleBooksResponse class. I think it has only one item which is list of items by looking at the output screenshot.

Comment: Added the GoogleBooksResponse Class too @KiranMachhewar

Comment: How GoogleBooks class look like.  do you have sample json you are geeing

Comment: You can take it from the endpoint. https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter

Comment: Please never include code as images. Text is much easier to use and accessible to search and screen readers, unlike images.

Comment: That is been used just for reference, because all my  other comments and changes were made accordingly with text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page block table value you need to assign items variable of each variable. Currently you are assigning the result in your case as per JSON only one value it will contain and the items variable of it contains all the list of Google books.
In your case if you use nested page block tables will solve you problem.

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="res">
            <apex:column value="{!res.kind}"/>
            <!-- Add rest of the columns you want to display of Result attributes-->

            <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="2">
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Books Information" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
<!-- iterating the books list-->
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!res.items}" var="item">
                        <apex:column value="{!item.kind}"/>
                        <!-- Add rest of the columns you want to display of Items attributes-->
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

If you don't want nested page block table then you can simply assign results[0].items to the value.

The class structure should be like this.

```
public class GoogleBooksResponse{
public  String kind{get;set;}
public  Integer totalItems{get;set;}
public  List<items> items{get;set;}
}
public class Items {
    public String kind {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public String etag {get;set;} 
    public String selfLink {get;set;} 

}
```

Comment: Tapas, How will be the Controller, Because i get Error: Unknown property 'GoogleBooksResponse.kind'

Comment: Kindly declare all the attributes inside GoogleBooksResponse as public, will solve the problem.

Comment: As you havn't declared any access specifiers to the inside attributes of the Class GoogleBooksResponse so its its setting access specifier as default while creating instance of that class due to which it is not visible to controller/page.

Comment: Tapas, Please check I have update the question and did the same was as insisted. help me to pass this through.

Comment: Kindly declare the attributes inside GoogleBooksResponse class as getter setter like u did for items class and declare item class outside the GoogleBooksResponse class.

Comment: Comment updated as well.

Comment: You are the CHAMP :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79390/discussion-between-kishore-and-tapas-tripathi).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updates below. you should not use local variable else your bind variable to page always be null and you need to point the local variable using item.

```
 public class SearchBooks {
        public GoogleBooksResponse result { get; set; }     

         public class Items {
            public String kind {get;set;} 
            public String id {get;set;} 
            public String etag {get;set;} 
            public String selfLink {get;set;} 

        }

        public searchBooksApi callsearch() {
            String s;
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
            req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter');
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = null;
            res = http.send(req);
            s = res.getBody();
            // Not a local variable
            result = (GoogleBooksResponse)  System.JSON.deserialize(s , GoogleBooksResponse.class);
            this.result = result;
            return null;
        }

         <apex:page controller="SearchBooks" >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!callsearch}" value="Search" id="theButton"/>
        </apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!result}" var="item">
    <!-- as you iterating GoogleBooksResponse it need to be a inner variable of that class -->
                <apex:column value="{!item.kind}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:page>
```

I Cannot paste the apex class here Please go here https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ and create the proper apex class to parse the response

Comment: I did this @avijit the problem is I get this error 
Error: Unknown property 'GoogleBooksResponse.kind'

Comment: can you post the JSON then only I can help Your class is not correct

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter this is the URL and this is the JSON (once after you click the link)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code in below way. GoogleBooksResponse contains list of items, which you need to use in value. In var you get single item and in column value you should be mapping the attribute of single item.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!result.items}" var="item">
    <!-- as you iterating GoogleBooksResponse it need to be a inner variable of that class -->
                <apex:column value="{!item.<PROPERTY FROM GoogleBooks Class>}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: <apex:column value="{!item.<PROPERTY FROM GoogleBooks Class>}"/> What excatly i have to add.. Because i tried {!item.kind} This dint work.
Error: Unknown property 'GoogleBooksResponse.items'

Comment: you need to past the structure of GoogleBooks. Since I dont the know the structure, I mentioned any property from that class. If you can paste the structure of that class then I can help you with the final code.